# Reflection error while creating spark session through Livy

Tags: scala, apache-spark, livy

I am creating a spark session through LivyClient.
The code for creating the session is -

```
var client: LivyClient = null
  try {
    client = new LivyClientBuilder()
      .setURI(new URI("http://127.0.0.1:4141"))
      .build();
    val pi = client.submit(new FileStream()).get
  } finally {
    client.stop(true)
  }
```

While creating a session, I am getting the error -

Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: object Predef does not have a member classOf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTqcu.png)

I am using the following versions -

1. Apache Livy - 0.5.0-incubating
2. Apache Spark - 2.3.0
3. Scala - 2.11 (2.11.8)

I have checked the scala-reflect version in all the three and they are same.

I am unable to understand what is causing the below error

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Images of errors are highly discouraged.Please [edit] your question and include the error as a text.

Comment: you should pass Livy Job to `client.submit` method

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  Did you ever find a resolution to this?

Answer (score 1):

What version of Java are you using?  It appears that changes in Java 9 regarding dropping of deprecated features stops Spark with errors referring to reflection.  The home page says that the Java must be at least version 8.